# Consistency of hyphenation of hyphenated words

Tags: lists, line-breaking, enumitem, hyphenation

This is not something I have encountered before and not sure which is the recommended way to hyphenate words with hyphens in them.

The MWE below yields two different results based on how the text is typeset. Note the beginning of the second line in each output:

[image]

### Question:

1. Main question is how do I make these two methods of typesetting text be consistent?
2. Since we are on the topic, which is the "correct" output?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=0pt,labelfont=sl}

\newlist{MyList*}{enumerate*}{1}%
\setlist[MyList*,1]{%
    label={\slshape Figure \arabic*:}, 
}%

\newcommand*{\TextWidth}{27.0em}

\newcommand*{\MyText}{%
    Some text to test hyphenation in words such as 
    left-and-right that already have dashes in them.%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw=red, thick, align=justify, text width=\TextWidth] 
        {%
            \begin{MyList*}
                \item \MyText%
            \end{MyList*}%
        };
\end{tikzpicture}%

\fboxsep=1pt
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\TextWidth}
    \captionof{figure}{\MyText}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've learned to divide hyphenated words at the hyphen, with this remaining in the first line. See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/351806. The second version is therefore in my (non-native speaker!) opinion the correct one.

Comment: This is an artifact of `enumerate*` which does “boxing and unboxing".

Comment: You can replicate it with `\sbox0{x left-and-right}\begin{minipage}{0pt}\unhbox0\end{minipage}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @egreg, the problem is `enumerate*`, and it's the result of two (IMO) misfeatures. The first one is the way TeX treats discretionaries when boxing text; the second one is `enumitem` sets `mode=boxed` by default. Two solutions, then.

1. Either use `luatex`, which fixes how discretionaries behave in boxes.
2. Or set `mode=unboxed`:

```
\setlist[MyList*,1]{%
  mode=unboxed,
  label={\slshape Figure \arabic*:}, 
}
```